# How to use function to call button instead of pressing it (swift3)

Tags: ios, function, button, swift3, ibaction

I want to be able to call function start within function use without hitting the action button for start. I know simple thing to do is just put print("a") in use. But I am using this as a simple example because I have a more complex problem in mind.

```
   @IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {
print("a")}


fun use() {
}

viewdidload() {
use()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `IBOutlet` for your button:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
```

Then simply, use this code to trigger its action:

```
button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider refactoring your functions. Instead of putting the button action code directly inside of the @IBAction function, put it in a separate function. This way, you can call this code from multiple places.

Here is one solution:

```
@IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {
    startAction()
}

func startAction() {
    print("a")
}

func use() {
    startAction()
    // anything else
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    use()
}
```